# Can't get images side by side

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage

I have been trying to get two images to be side by side using subfigure or minipage and I am not sure why it isn't working. Below is what I have written to try get them to be beside each other but no matter what I do the end up centered and below each other. Maybe I am doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance!

````
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/sampleassembly.PNG}
        \caption{Inventor assembly of sample set-up}
        \label{fig:sampleassembly}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/detectorassembly.PNG}
        \caption{Inventor assembly of detector set-up}
        \label{fig:detectorassembly}
    \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}```
````

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Even though the two subfigures are narrow enough to fit on the same line, the presence of a blank line between them causes a paragraph break.  Either omit the blank line, enter a `%` at the beginning to ignore it, or insert an explicit space to separate them (`\quad` may be appropriate).  (This has undoubtedly been asked before, but I haven't found a suitable instance.)